# How to change Timezone in SQL Query?

Tags: sql, timezone

How to change Timezone in SQL Query?

I want to convert datetime into other timezone e.g Bangkok UTC +0700

For example
2021-07-04 20:08:15

Expected Result
2021-07-05 03:08:15

Comment: syntax depends on your dbms , tag your dbms

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't tag your RDBMS, I will post for `SQL Server`, `MySQL` and `PostgreSQL`.

### SQL Server

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'2021-07-04T20:08:15') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'SE Asia Standard Time'
```

### MySQL

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2021-07-04 20:08:15','UTC','+07:00');
```

### PostgreSQL

```
SELECT '2021-07-04 20:08:15'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE '+07:00'
```

Note: I don't know name of your time zone, so replace if you know.